# is the kaa application modularity？

Tags: server, structure, kaa

Kaa demo show lots of example of application&client,but actually in the fact solution, may need some of function together,
so,question is:
one client (e.g. android app) access the multiple function (e.g. 2 function:event and notifications)in the server,so:

1. i need put all function in one application,or
2. create 2 applications,android app access the different function separate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the SDK API (functions) or all at the same time (within single client application). The Kaa Sample Applications were made with an intent to be as simple (thus clear and easy to understand) as possible. Therefore, just for simplicity most of the samples use just one Kaa feature. This does not mean that they cannot be used in a single application at the same time.

Please feel free putting them all into a single application.